# Client side validation is not firing for RequiredIf

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am using *ExpressiveAnnotations* by [JaroslawWaliszko](https://github.com/JaroslawWaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations). It works fine when I check server side through `ModelState.IsValid`. But it is not showing client side validation message. I don't know what things are missing. I have added *jquery* file too. Here is property on which I have applied `RequiredIf`:

```
// When Role = Assistant Professor(which has id = 3), 
// His/ Her head's Id should be selected as ParentID.

[RequiredIf("RoleID == 3", ErrorMessage = "Select Head.")] 
public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }
```

Rendered HTML is as below:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" 
        data-val="true" 
        data-val-number="The field ParentID must be a number." 
        data-val-requiredif="Select Head." 
        data-val-requiredif-allowempty="false" 
        data-val-requiredif-constsmap="{}" 
        data-val-requiredif-expression="RoleID == 3" 
        data-val-requiredif-fieldsmap="{"RoleID":"numeric"}" 
        id="ParentID" 
        name="ParentID" 
        ng-model="DTO.ParentID" 
        ng-options="obj.Value as obj.Text for obj in headList">

    <option selected="selected" value="" class="">--select--</option>
    <option value="0">Mr. Kevin Thomas</option>
    <option value="1">Ms. Lisa Brown</option>
    <option value="2">Mr. Sail Kapoor</option>
</select>
```

Things I have implemented:

1. Installed package: *Install-Package ExpressiveAnnotations*,
2. Added below code in *Global.asax*

   ```
   DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
       typeof (RequiredIfAttribute), typeof (RequiredIfValidator));
   DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
       typeof (AssertThatAttribute), typeof (AssertThatValidator));
   ```
3. Added *expressive.annotations.validate.js* in bundle below *jquery* validation files, and added bundle on specified page.

Comment: Have your included `@HtmlValidationMessageFor(m => m.ParentID)`? Something also looks wrong with the first option - have you created this manually?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes I have.

Comment: Any reason for not using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ParentID)`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke It will have list of heal employees. from that one must select if you are registering new employee which is at lower designation.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand - whats that go to do with not using the html helper?

Comment: I'm sure it's too late, but some of your JS libraries could have been loaded twice, [see troubleshooting steps](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations/issues/107).

Answer (score 2):

It looks quite ok to me. Are there any errors on console output?

You can try this which works for me:

```
public class Model
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Supervisors
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Mr. Kevin Thomas", Value = "0"},
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Ms. Lisa Brown", Value = "1"},
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Mr. Sail Kapoor", Value = "2"}
            };
        }
    }

    [RequiredIf("RoleID == 3", ErrorMessage = "Select Head.")]
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    ...
```

and view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParentID, Model.Supervisors, "--select--")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentID)
```

Also, unless you already seen it, take a look at [sample project](https://github.com/JaroslawWaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations/tree/master/src/ExpressiveAnnotations.MvcWebSample) where you can find few similar cases.

**UPDATE:**

[Look here for few troubleshooting steps](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations/issues/107).

Comment: The correct way is to delete the first `SelectListItem` and use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ParentID, Model.Supervisors, "--select--")` No point creating another select list when `Model.Supervisors` is already a select list, and the last parameter correctly renders a 'null' label option - `<option value>--select--</option>`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: Thanks, I fully agree - answer adjusted to reflect your advice.